# Flash message contents lost in layout

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller, flash-message

This is the scenario:
I have layout : main.gsp 
and have a page on which this layout is applied: homepage.gsp
I have a div in main.gsp where I display flash message if any.

Now, 
when controller sends any flash message, its available in homepage.gsp but when layout is applied on it and page is displayed, flash message is lost.

I want flash message to be available in layout code.
Again, it would be preferable if I need not add any code to homepage.gsp as there are many such pages where controller can return flash message.

How do I handle this? 
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Add the layout, homepage and controller code to the question.

Comment: actually the codes are too big to be posted here.please let me know if there is any specific details that I can give you. I will paste that part of code.

Comment: You don't need to post the whole files, just the parts that has something to do with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I will used, I have tested and it work.
main.gsp

```
    <body>
    <div id="grailsLogo" role="banner"><a href="http://grails.org"><img src="${resource(dir: 'images', file: 'grails_logo.png')}" alt="Grails"/></a></div>
    <div>
        <g:if test="${flash.message }">
        ${flash.message }
        </g:if>
    </div>
    <g:layoutBody/>
    <div class="footer" role="contentinfo"></div>
    <div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;"><g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/></div>
    <r:layoutResources />
</body>
```

Controller:

```
    package com.mtsinai

class EmployeeController {

    def index() { 
        flash.message = 'Welcome world'
    }
}
```

**index.gsp**

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="body">

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the flash message will be displayed on top of the body or the page that will be rendered